# Updating multiple objects at once

Tags: django, django-views

I have a function that should update all objects that are created by a user to an inactive state. So i coded this:

```
def TurnOff(request, passed_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():

        #this should set all objects to an inactive state
        tmp = myModel.objects.filter(created_by=request.user).update(active=False)

        #this is to set one specific object to an active state again
        myModel = get_object_or_404(myModel, created_by=request.user, pk=passed_id)
        tmp = myModel.objects.filter(created_by=request.user, pk=passed_id).update(active=True)

        return HttpResponseRedirect("../started")

    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

The line `tmp = myModel.objects.filter(created_by=request.user).update(active=False)` is not working (that means false is not set), only if i specify the filter with the additional keyword `pk=ANY_ID`, but i want to update all objects like its described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)!

Comment: A pk refers to a specific individual object. If you want to update all objects, why are you filtering by pk?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The filter that should return all objects has no pk filtering attribute, only the second filter does that to reactivate one specific object.

Comment: How do you know it does not work, if you loop after the first filter, on myModel.objects.filter(created_by=request.user) and print the active, what do you get?

Comment: @GaliaLadirayWeiss Because i do somewhere else `MyModel.objects.filter(created_by=request.user, active=True)` and this returns me more than 1 object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, replace your following line,

```
tmp = myModel.objects.filter(created_by=request.user, pk=passed_id).update(active=True)
```

with the following :

```
tmp.active = False
tmp.save()
```

**EDITED**

Since 'tmp' is an object of your myModel and it returns only one object since you're using pk for retrieving it.

Comment: No this will give me only one object, because pk is set.

Comment: In that case, replace your following line, 
`tmp = myModel.objects.filter(created_by=request.user, pk=passed_id).update(active=True)` with 

`tmp.active=True`  and `tmp.save()`

Since tmp is an object of myModel.

Comment: This wasn't my solution but gave me a hint to the solution: With `tmp = myModel.objects.all()`, `for i in tmp: i.active = False i.save()` it works.

Comment: @rwx This is not ideal, the idea behind update() of a queryset, is that it updates the database once, your solution will have poor performance. But maybe performance is not that important in your case. Anyway, I tend to suspect maybe some other part of the code, that you did not put in the your post

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
# after this line myModel is not Model anymore, but instance of myModel
# with created_by=request.user and pk=passed_id
myModel = get_object_or_404(myModel, created_by=request.user, pk=passed_id)
# so this line doesn't work
tmp = myModel.objects.filter(created_by=request.user, pk=passed_id).update(active=True)
```

to

```
# you want to update _one_ instance, don't you?
tmp = get_object_or_404(myModel, created_by=request.user, pk=passed_id)
tmp.active = True
tmp.save()
```